Let $U$ be a continuous random variable. Can we find the pdf of $W= g(U) f(U)$ where $g$ and $f$ are strictly increasing.
Let $U$ be a continuous random variable. Can we find the pdf of $W= g(U) f(U)$ where $g$ and $f$ are strictly increasing.
Here is what I have been able to do to
\begin{align}
F_W(w) &= P [f(U) g(U) \le w] \\
&= P[ V g(f^{-1}(V)) \le w]
\end{align}
Therefore, the problem can be reduced to study the distribution of $V \cdot h(V)$. At this point we have
\begin{align}
f_W(w) = \frac{d}{d w} P [ V h(V) \le w] = \frac{d}{d w} \int _{V h(V) \le w}  f_V(w) dv
\end{align}
But how to simplify this derivative?

This is how I would approach this problem.
Since $f$ and $g$ are strictly increasing, we know that $h(u)=g(u)f(u)$ is strictly increasing.  This ensures $h$ is invertible and admits a well-defined inverse function $h^{-1}(w)$, satisfying $u=h^{-1}(w)$ whenever $w=h(u)$. Also $h'(u)=g'(u)f(u)+g(u)f'(u)$. Using the standard formula for a monotonic transformation, the pdf of $W$ is $$f_W(w) = f_U\big(h^{-1}(w)\big) \left| \frac{d}{dw} \big[h^{-1}(w)\big] \right|
= \frac{f_U(h^{-1}(w))}{h'(h^{-1}(w))}, $$ where I used the inverse function rule. Substituting $h(u) = g(u) f(u)$ and its derivative $h'(u)$, we obtain$$f_W(w) = 
\frac{
    f_U\big(h^{-1}(w)\big)
}{
    g'\big(h^{-1}(w)\big) f\big(h^{-1}(w)\big)+g\big(h^{-1}(w)\big) f'\big(h^{-1}(w)\big)
}$$ for all $w \in \operatorname{Range}(h)$, which is determined by the range of $g(u)f(u)$.
